# KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs

Tags: vb.net, button, onclick, enter, eventargs

I'm trying to make a button that handles both enters and clicks. I've set up my sub procedure to handle both keyups and mouse clicks, however I cannot access MouseEventArgs from EventrArs nor KeyEventArgs from System.EventArgs. How can I do such?

Comment: You can't do that. Tell us why you are doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question isnt exactly clear, it sounds like you are trying to key keyboard events "from" `System.EventArgs`?

I'm not exactly sure what your asking, but posting code with your question would help us give accurate answers.

The following i assume I am guessing what you are asking is relevant to the sample below:

`EventArgs` is a type, it is also the base type for all events.

It seems you want a subroutine that can handle both Click and Keypresses in one go.

The following subroutine 'e_Handler' will accept `MouseEventArgs`, `KeyEventArgs`, and `KeyPressEventArgs` by checking the event type and casting it to a variable, in which u can then test or use the resulting states accordingly.:

```
' Handler for 3 event types:

Sub e_Handler(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)

    If TypeOf E Is MouseEventArgs Then
        Dim K As MouseEventArgs = CTypeDynamic(Of MouseEventArgs)(E)

        MsgBox("Clicked Mouse at position " & K.Location.ToString & " on " & Sender.ToString)
    End If

    If TypeOf E Is KeyPressEventArgs Then
        Dim K As KeyPressEventArgs = CTypeDynamic(Of KeyPressEventArgs)(E)

        MsgBox("Pressed the key " & K.KeyChar & " on " & Sender.ToString)
    End If

    If TypeOf E Is KeyEventArgs Then
        Dim K As KeyEventArgs = CTypeDynamic(Of KeyEventArgs)(E)

        MsgBox("Pressed the key " & K.KeyCode & " on " & Sender.ToString)
    End If

    Me.Text = E.ToString

End Sub
```

You can then make this routine the handler for any number of events and controls:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    AddHandler Me.MouseClick, AddressOf e_Handler
    AddHandler Me.KeyPress, AddressOf e_Handler
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf e_Handler


    For Each C As Control In Me.Controls
        AddHandler C.MouseClick, AddressOf e_Handler
        AddHandler C.KeyDown, AddressOf e_Handler
        AddHandler C.KeyPress, AddressOf e_Handler
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit:

The use of `CTypeDynamic` is to avoid compiler "implicit conversion" warnings, and ensures the method wont throw and exception if you set your project to compile with **Option Strict**

Comment: I have solved the problem a different way by using `Me.AcceptButton` property.